# JS Return value from function with mysql query

Tags: javascript, node.js

there is a certain function from which it is necessary to pull out value.

```
function func () {
  let a

  sql = `SELECT * FROM ...`
  db.query(sql, function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err
    a = ...
  })
  return a
}
func()

let per = func()
```

But all the time undefined. This is solved by async / await ?

Comment: The function inside the query call is a callback function, which means it is executed *after* the query has completed.  You cannot use `return` with asynchronous methods.  Instead you should have the code you want to execute afterwards in a function and call that function (with the results as a parameter) from inside the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a callback function (or a promise)

```
function func(cb) {
  sql = `SELECT * FROM ...`
  db.query(sql, function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err
    cb(results)
  })
}

func((a) => {
  console.log(a); // results of the query
})
```